# How can i read a text file and create a 'if else' according to text, using python?

Tags: python

file.txt contains only "1" number.

I tried this but didn't worked.

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
if file.read() == "1":
    print("something")
else:
    print("else")
file.close()
```

Comment: have you tried print(file.read()) ? Check what it is actually returning, chances are its not "1"

Comment: I would try `file.read().strip() == '1'`

Comment: You probably have a space or newline in your file. Also you need a colon after your `else` statement.

Comment: But, more specifically, **what** didn't work? Your code or your logic? As mentioned already, your code won't compile.

Comment: i tried print(file.read()), it shows only 1. but if 'else' doesn't work, also there is no space or newline in file for sure.

Comment: the problem is print("something") or print("else") doesn't appear.

Comment: @suayipuzulmez What else appears? Something *must* appear.

Comment: Why is there no `:` after the `else`?

Comment: there is no problem with code. i write it messy (sorry). an error doesn't appears too.

Comment: In your file editor make whitespace and newlines visible. Check there isn't anything else in the file other than the `1`.

Comment: ok, i tried to write on idle, it works. i was using the pycharm text editor. there's must be problem with editor. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. You are missing a `:` after `else`.

`file.txt` content (no new line or trailing space)

```
1
```

Code

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    if file.read().strip() == '1':
        print("something")
    else:
        print("else")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
if file.read() == "1":
    print("something")
else:
    print("else")
file.close()
```